# Prefer home WiFi over tethering WiFi

Tags: network-manager, mobile-broadband

I have 2 WiFi sources:

- Home WiFi, unlimited.
- Mobile Broadband WiFi, limited. I want to use it only when there is no other choice.

How to set NetworkManager to switch from Mobile WiFi as soon as Home WiFi is within reach?

Deactivating Mobile Broadband WiFi as soon as I enter home is not a good solution, as it would take too much time, I go in and out very often.

A fork of NetworkManager could be a solution, even if it involves hard-coding.

Comment: have you tried `wifi-radar`? may be making HomeWifi preferred will do the trick? http://askubuntu.com/a/165690/46437

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now available in Gnome Network Manager (`nm-connection-editor`) in the *General* section.  Give the connection priority for auto-activation a higher value on your preferred network.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQK0W.png]

Comment: Higher numbers have more priority. I've revised my screen shot to include the rollover text to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager itself doesn't sadly support this, there was a quite long discussion on this in years, try checking out:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/366780

An external solution could be an idea (a script in background checking *iwlist scanning* output and manually switching?) that I implemented also tiem ago but I don't know if this sounds viable for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, a script would be better than nothing, of course :-)

Comment: The launchpad page is definitely in the right direction, but slightly different: It says "nobody here suggested changing the active connection". I would like to switch, even if that means losing the connection for a few seconds.