# Change default wifi sort order

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager

By default, Ubuntu lists nearby wireless networks sorted alphabetically, regardless of the signal strength.

How can I set the list to be displayed in order of wi-fi signal power?

[image]

Comment: I believe this is hard-coded and can't be changed in nm-applet. For an alternative (wifi-radar) see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of `network-manager-applet` is by design and can't be changed.

From the bugtracker:

> We do understand that at the very first time you setup your computer
>   (or when you're travelling somewhere), there is a need to select
>   networks from a list (potentially fairly long) which is alphabetically
>   listed; however;
>
> - this is only for the first time you go to a specific location. After that, your "favorite" networks float to the top, followed by a
>     number of other networks (up to five in the "main" menu), then all
>     others to a submenu, all of which alphabetically listed.
> - alphabetical listing makes sense following the concept that it's the natural way to look for a known network name -- which is the most
>     common use cases: you know the name of your home network, if you go to
>     someone's house, they would tell you the SSID to use, etc.
> - your "home" network will not always be at the highest strength (which is especially true where there are lots of wifi networks in
>     range, due to factors such as interference)
>
> As such, I'll mark this bug as "Won't Fix". Thanks!

([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/485041))

Answer (score -1):

I have 2 home routers set to different dns's.

On the router that I don't want to use, I turned the setting to "automatically connect to this network when it is available" off in the corresponding profile.

This way when I start my computer, it connects to the router that I want, perhaps this may work for you as well.