# Can I instruct gnome network manager NOT to connect to a specific network

Tags: network-manager, wicd

In a client workplace, they have a secured wifi connection and a unsecured client-guest network. My laptop is automatically connecting  to this Guest network, and by doing so, this leaves me unable to remote into any machine (rightfully so). It's a mild annoyance, but repeatedly this lost time adds up.

May I instruct gnome to *never* connect to certain networks?

Failing that, would using [Wicd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicd) be a reliable alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority

Comment: @ravery That question mentions a python tool, which is great, yes! But, I'd like to handle this directly through a `conf` file or disabling a network through the interfaces provided by network-manager. I find loading additional utilities can sometimes complicate a situation more than help.

Comment: see the second answer

Comment: Can we assume that simply unchecking the `Automatically connect to this network when it is available` box doesn't provide a solution in this case?

Comment: @steeldriver that works in Unity Network Manager GUI. In GNOME it's a little different. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the GNOME WiFi network settings panel
- locate the guest network and click on the gear icon
- click `reset` in the left pane
- click the `forget` button