# How to blacklist a WiFi network by its SSID in Linux

Tags: networking, wireless, blacklist

I'm looking to set up some dual-boot laptops for an IT security class, but want to prevent them from connecting to some specific WiFi networks by SSID name.  I know how to do this on Windows 10 thanks to [this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/block-wifi-network-windows10/), but would also like to do the same in the laptop's Ubuntu partition.

To be clear, I don't want to downgrade the networks or make them less visible, or less likely to be joined automatically. I want to make them invisible to users from the dropdown WiFi menu and in the settings app, just like the solution in Windows 10.

I've not had much luck searching for how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage available wireless network priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority)

Comment: Not really. Marking certain networks as low priority for autoconnecting to might make them less visible, but it dosen't hide them from the students. I'd rather put those networks out of temptation's way by blacklisting them on the device.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1434084/edit) and add why your question is not a duplicate of the linked question including a link to the question.